# Render a view while Ajax expects a response

Tags: ajax, express

I am building an express project, using ejs as a view engine, and AJAX for front-end http calls.

When I post a request such this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   data: {'nickname' :  $('#nickname').val()},
   contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   url: 'http://localhost:5000/create',
   success: function(data) {
     $('#message').text("Unkwon error");
   },
   error: function(data){
      $('#message').text('Something went wrong, check connection!');
   }
```

The Ajax keeps waiting for a response, which I am not willing to give, as I just want to render a view as follows :

```
app.post('/create', urlencodedParser, (req, res)=>{
   let code = unique.generate(rooms);
   res.render('chat', {'nickname' : req.body.nickname, 'code' : code}
```

Any ideas how can I work around this?

Comment: What does this mean: ***"The Ajax keeps waiting for a response, which I am not willing to give"***?

Comment: I mean that any data will be sent to the 'res' object, will be sent back to the Ajax function - which's not capable of rendering an ejs page -.

Comment: I am thinking of not giving the Ajax any response, and find a way to redirect this response to the html dom, which can do the rendering.

Comment: The ajax needs to have some response just so the http connection doesn't just sit there unfinished for a long time.  Your client is free to ignore the response if it wants to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found a way to do it.

Basically, I can just tell the Ajax to attach the document sent from rendering to the html body

```
$('body').html(data);
```

Surprisingly, this works event with Ejs dynamic tags.

I know it's not the best way to do it, but it's the only one I found till now.

**EDIT 1:**

After few months, I realized the solution is simple as just changing the Location using javascript

```
window.location.replace(`http://localhost:5000/newRequest`);
```

Now, I could handle this new request separately on the server.

**EDIT 2:**

After couple years now, I realized a `GET` request might have solved the problem in a single round trip.